# Prove that $x/y$ < $(x+3)/(y-3)$ obeys the condition $-x<y$ only for y<0

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this original equation
$x/y < (x+3)/(y-3)$. For this equation to be true, by cross multiplying the denominators, I arrive at the simpler condition, $-x<y$.

But on trial and error, i put negative values of $x$ say $x=-5$, I get the result as
$-5/y < 2/(y-3)$ which reduces to $y>15/7$. 
So for $y=4$ and $x=-5$, the original equation holds but the arrived condition $-x<y$ doesn't hold.

So, how can i theoretically prove the original equation implies $-x<y$ not for all combinations of $x$ and $y$ but only when $y<0$.

Comment: If you multiply an inequality by a  negative number the inequality sign gets reversed. ($1<2$ but $(-1)(1)>(-1)(2)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the sign table:

\begin{array}{|c|ccccc|}
\require{enclose}
\hline 
&&0&&3\\
\hline
y&-&|&-&\enclose{verticalstrike}{0}&+ \\
\hline
y-3&-&\enclose{verticalstrike}{0}&+&|&+ \\
\hline
y(y-3)&+&\enclose{verticalstrike}{0}&-&\enclose{verticalstrike}{0}&+ \\ \hline
\end{array}

We have to considere 3 distinct cases

1. $y = 0$ or $y =3$ . Then one term of the inequality is undefined
2. $y < 0$ or $y > 3$ . Then
   $$\frac x y<\frac{x+3}{y-3} \iff x(y-3)<(x+3)y\iff -x < y$$
3. $0<y<3$. Then
   $$\frac x y<\frac{x+3}{y-3} \iff x(y-3)>(x+3)y\iff -x>y$$